# How can I convert a decimal year value into a Date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

Input:

> 2015.0596924

Desired output:

> January 22, 2015

Comment: did you already know the answer before posting it? 'coz you answer your own question in less than a minute

Comment: @DyrandzFamador, of course he did, but that's done fairly often. I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had been working off a couple other ideas, mostly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058630/javascript-function-to-convert-decimal-years-value-into-years-months-and-days, but I didn't see a place that had code for accurately getting the correct day. Just posting here so the next person could use it and you all could make fun of my code.

Comment: @DyrandzFamador there is an option when you ask a question to "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". I just used that, even while I knew it wasn't the most efficient solution (and I was proven very correct in that)

Comment: @AlienLifeForm, yeah there's no problem with that.  Jon skeet also doing that for sharing his knowledge. :) actually, i see no problem, i only ask that question just to confirm if you already know the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a formatted date as follows:

```
require 'date'

d = 2015.0596924
year = Date.new(d)
  #=> #<Date: 2015-01-01 ((2457024j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
date = (year + (year.leap? ? 366 : 365) * (d % 1))
  #=> #<Date: 2015-01-22 ((2457045j,68059s,526396957n),+0s,2299161j)> 
date.strftime("%B %d, %Y") 
  #=> "January 22, 2015"
```

Comment: That is so much easier than what I did (below). Embarrassing and thank you.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed, as we all need to start somewhere. I can see from your choice of camel-case variable names (the Ruby convention is snake-case for `both_variables_and_methods`) that you are fairly new to Ruby. It probably also means you have some un-learnin' to do.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, maybe you can also improve upon my Javascript version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400171/how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-year-value-into-a-date-in-javascript/29400172

Comment: "Javascript"? Never heard of it. Something to do with coffee?. My present repertoire is just Ruby without Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.

```
# @param decimalDate [String] the date in decimal form, but can be a String or a Float
# @return [DateTime] the converted date
def decimal_year_to_datetime(decimalDate)
  decimalDate = decimalDate.to_f
  year = decimalDate.to_i # Get just the integer part for the year
  daysPerYear = leap?(year) ? 366 : 365 # Set days per year based on leap year or not
  decimalYear = decimalDate - year # A decimal representing portion of the year left
  dayOfYear = (decimalYear * daysPerYear).ceil # day of Year: 1 to 355 (or 366)
  md = getMonthAndDayFromDayOfYear(dayOfYear, year)

  DateTime.new(year,md[:month],md[:day])
end

# @param dayOfYear [Integer] the date in decimal form
# @return [Object] month and day in an object
def getMonthAndDayFromDayOfYear(dayOfYear, year)
  daysInMonthArray = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  daysInMonthArray[2] = 29 if leap?(year)

  daysLeft = dayOfYear
  month = 0
  daysInMonthArray.each do |daysInThisMonth|
    if daysLeft > daysInThisMonth
      month += 1 
      daysLeft -= daysInThisMonth
    else
      break
    end
  end
  return { month: month, day: daysLeft }
end

# @param year [Integer]
# @return [Boolean] is this year a leap year?
def leap?(year)
  return year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0
end
```