# How do I convert a decimal year value into a Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

OK, this is basically a Javascript version of [How can I convert a decimal year value into a Date in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381595/how-can-i-convert-a-decimal-year-value-into-a-date-in-ruby) and not *exactly* a duplicate of [Javascript function to convert decimal years value into years, months and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058630/javascript-function-to-convert-decimal-years-value-into-years-months-and-days)

Input:

> 2015.0596924

Desired output:

> January 22, 2015

I have solved it (see below), but I expect (just like the Ruby version of this question) that there is a better way.

Comment: Please define "*[decimal year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#Scientific_decimal_time)*". How would a conversion work? Where do you get your input from? Is there any specification?

Comment: By "decimal year" I mean a decimal that tells you the year and how far towards the next year you are... so 2014.99999 would be right before you kiss your baby on New Years 2015 and 2015.00001 would be right after the kiss ends. 2015.5 would be directly in the middle of the year.

Comment: Ok, so `year + 1` would not necessarily the same day as `year`. Odd. But it seems you can do something similar simple to the ruby code in js.

Comment: Only if it were a leap year vs. non-leap year would it be different. Ruby's Date method allows you to give it a decimal year. Javascript's does not. Looks like the milliseconds method is the most succinct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution would be:

1. Create `date` for given year (integer part)
2. Calculate days from reminder (decimal part) and convert to milliseconds
3. Add milliseconds to (1)

In script:

```js
function leapYear(year) {
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
};

function convertDecimalDate(decimalDate) {
    var year = parseInt(decimalDate);
    var reminder = decimalDate - year;
    var daysPerYear = leapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
    var miliseconds = reminder * daysPerYear * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var yearDate = new Date(year, 0, 1);
    return new Date(yearDate.getTime() + miliseconds);
}

var date = convertDecimalDate(2015.0596924);
console.log(date);
```

You can play with it on **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLp2obvf/1/)**.

Comment: Props to @Pete for the millisecond solution, but the need to handle leap years means that this is the correct succinct answer. I edited to provide better output. Thanks guys!

Comment: We just wrote similar answers same time, you can see the difference is two minutes. In fact I would be first to post, but I decided than to create a playground on Fiddle. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will resolve the dates for you if you add too much time. See demonstration below. The solution below doesn't calculate the leap year based on the algorithm, but takes next year's date and subtracts it from this year. This assumes that the JavaScript specification properly calculates leap years.

See [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

```js
function decimalDateToJsDate(time) {
  var year = Math.floor(time);
  var thisYear = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  var nextYear = new Date(year + 1, 0, 1);
  var millisecondsInYear = nextYear.getTime() - thisYear.getTime();
  var deltaTime = Math.ceil((time - year) * millisecondsInYear);
  thisYear.setMilliseconds(deltaTime);
  return thisYear;
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = decimalDateToJsDate(2015.0596924);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks! Learned something new today. Good thing we don't have to account for [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: What do you mean "if you add too much time"?

Comment: "This assumes that the JavaScript specification properly calculates leap years." - I just did some testing and Date.getTime() does not return different values for leap years.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm Hhmmm.. I wonder if it is browser dependent. On this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18q0tvhu/) I was able to get the correct number of days for the leap years. I know that the JS spec doesn't account for the [missing days](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-gregorian-switch.html) on the Gregorian  calendar. Do you have the test cases where the leap year values don't work? I'm just curious why this could be.

Answer (score 1):

```
function leapYear (year){
  return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

function getMonthAndDayFromDayOfYear(dayOfYear, year){
  var daysInMonthArray = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  if (leapYear(year)) { daysInMonthArray[2] = 29; }

  var daysLeft = dayOfYear;
  var month = 0;
  for (i=0; i<daysInMonthArray.length; i++) {
    var daysInThisMonth = daysInMonthArray[i];
    if (daysLeft > daysInThisMonth) {
      month += 1;
      daysLeft -= daysInThisMonth;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return { month: month, day: daysLeft };
}

function convertDecimalDate(decimalDate){
  decimalDate = parseFloat(decimalDate);
  var year = parseInt(decimalDate); // Get just the integer part for the year
  var daysPerYear = leapYear(year) ? 366 : 365; // Set days per year based on leap year or not
  var decimalYear = decimalDate - year; // A decimal representing portion of the year left
  var dayOfYear = Math.ceil(decimalYear * daysPerYear); // day of Year: 1 to 355 (or 366)
  var md = getMonthAndDayFromDayOfYear(dayOfYear, year);
  var day = md['day'];
  var month = md['month'];
  return new Date(year,month,day);
}

var date = convertDecimalDate(2015.0596924);
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that figuring out a leap year wasn't just a year divisible by 4. Didn't realize that there was more to it than that.